# How to set Dockerfile's RUN Command exec one by one?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sentry

There is a problem when the command result is asynchronous. It will return a error of `a non-zero code`

So, How do I separate them that can be execute one by one.

```
COPY --from=builder /app/src/environments/env.sh /home
WORKDIR /home
RUN cd /home && source env.sh \
  && sentry-cli releases new $VERSION \
  && sentry-cli releases set-commits --auto $VERSION \
  && sentry-cli releases files $VERSION upload-sourcemaps . \
  && sentry-cli releases finalize $VERSION
```

Particularly, `sentry-cli releases files $VERSION upload-sourcemaps` is an upload command.

[From Gitlab Example](https://medium.com/angular-athens/make-angulars-source-code-available-to-sentry-with-gitlab-ci-b3020bd60ae6)

Comment: Separate commands by semicolon.

Comment: They _should_ run sequentially – the shell `&&` operator waits for the previous command to execute and runs the next command only if its exit status is 0.  If your `upload-sourcemaps` command is asynchronous (it starts the upload in the background and returns immediately) the shell has no direct way to wait for it.

Comment: So, what you really need? Want to continue next command only if `async command finish` or `the async command return non-zero make you docker build issue`?